# List of theorems stating that P does not equal NP if and only if

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, big-list, p-vs-np

I think it would be a good idea to make a list of theorems stating that P does not equal NP if and only if such and such exits, some complexity class is contained in another complexity class and so on and so forth.

Comment: That would be a constant fraction of all complexity papers!

Comment: I would say: "list of conditions implying P?NP", since not all those theorems are "if and only if". Also, I guess people are more interested --in general-- in knowing how to prove P?NP by proving something else, than in listing the many consequences of this result, a topic that has been widely discussed elsewhere.

Comment: @Janoma: if you want to restrict yourself to implications, then the list will be really huge, given the enormous amount of results of the form: "If P!=NP, then problem X cannot be solved exactly / approximated within a constant factor in polynomial time". The question should be much more focused or better stated if we want to avoid that.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre: I said "list of conditions **implying** P?NP", not **implied by** P?NP. That is, a list of statements of the form "**If** [condition], **then** P=NP" or "**If** [condition], **then** P!=NP". The idea, as I hinted, is to avoid "listing the many consequences of this result" (P=NP or P!=NP).

Comment: @Janoma: That does not solve Anthony’s well-founded concern.  Hypotheses which imply P=NP are simply negations of consequences of P≠NP, and hypotheses which imply P≠NP are negations of consequences of P=NP.  If SAT is solvable in polynomial time, then P=NP.  If Max3SAT is polynomial-time approximable within a constant factor less than 8/7, then P=NP.  And so on.

Comment: @Tsuyoshilto: true, but I guess many of the problems will fall under a same category (e.g. for any NP-complete problem *X* we can say "If *X* is solvable in polynomial time, then P=NP"). Still, given these observations, I'd say that a better question (for a wiki, perhaps), would be maintaining a list of statements directly implied by or implying one of the outcomes of P?NP, not in the philosophical, "Impagliazzo's Worlds" sense, but in a more "mathematical" (for lack of a better word) fashion (for example: "if P=NP then there are polynomial-time algorithms for problems X, Y and Z").

Comment: @Janoma: "If X then P=NP" is the same as "If P≠NP then not-X".

Comment: a well known open, apparently stronger conjecture than $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ is that there are no polynomial-sized circuits over the complete basis (AND,OR,NOT gates) to solve $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problems. but it is not known if $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ implies that such circuits dont exist.

Comment: this doesn't seem like a real question, but a list. I think this is considered off-topic now that we can't make 'community wiki' questions. Although I think such a resource would be useful, I am not sure if cstheory is the best way to produce such a resource.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a one:

Mahaney's Theorem: There is no sparse NP-complete set if and only if $P \ne NP $
(under Karp reduction).

Another one is:

$P \ne NP$ if and only if $P \ne PH$

Comment: May be this is straightforward: $P \ne NP$ if and only if $FP \ne FNP$.

Answer (score 11):

$P \ne NP$ if and only if worst-case one-way functions exist.

Reference:

Alan L. Selman. A survey of one-way functions in complexity theory. Mathematical
systems theory, 25(3):203–221, 1992.

Comment: a ref would be good

Comment: Are you sure? I hadn't heard of worst-case OWFs before, but from the notes [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs687/2006fa/lectures/lecture3.pdf) it looks like their existence is equivalent to $BPP \neq NP$.

Comment: Yes I am sure. :) See the reference.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a result from descriptive complexity theory:

$P \ne NP$ if and only if some second order property is not expressible using first order logic plus least fixed point.

Reference:
Immerman, [Languages that capture complexity classes](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/pub/LanguagesWhichSTOC83.pdf)

Comment: ... on ordered structures. Otherwise we know unconditionally that such properties exist.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek yes, on ordered structures as it was implicitly assumed by Immerman in above paper.

Answer (score 7):

Ladner theorem can be stated as:

$P \ne NP$ if and only if there exists an incomplete set in $NP-P$.

Incomplete set is a set that is not complete for $NP$ under many-one polynomial time reductions.

Reference

Complexity Theory and Cryptology: An Introduction to Cryptocomplexity
 By Jörg Rothe, page 106